# GeoIP PHP extension not working on CentOS 7

Tags: php, httpd, geoip

I can't get the GeoIP PHP extension working on CentOS 7 and PHP 5.5.21.

I first started with `yum install php-pecl-geoip` and restarted httpd. I then did a simple test:

```
$record = geoip_record_by_name($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
if ($record) {
    print_r($record);
}
```

I got an error 500, and in the error log, I see

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function geoip_record_by_name()`

So I figured the yum package was bad and removed it. I then did `pecl install geoip` and enabled the extension `/etc/php.d/geoip.ini` with `extension=geoip.so` and restarted httpd. Same error - undefined function.

To make sure the install was correct, I tried the pecl install again and received this output:

`pecl/geoip is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.0.8`

I do have Apache's mod_geoip installed. Do the 2 conflict with each other?

What else can I check?

Comment: Are you using PHP as an Apache module?

Comment: @MichaelHampton PHP was installed as part of yum. I do see `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp55-php5.so` in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php55-php.conf`, so I am going to say Yes PHP is loaded as an Apache module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've obtained PHP 5.5 from Red Hat Software Collections. Unfortunately this SCL doesn't include the PECL geoip extension, so you will need to install it yourself.

```
scl enable php55 'pecl install geoip'
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I get this error when I try that command as root: `Unable to open /etc/scl/conf/pecl!`. I think we're onto something but unsure what to do next.

Comment: OK, maybe you didn't use a Software Collection. Where exactly _did_ you get PHP from?

Comment: `yum info php55` returns the following info: `From repo   : centos-sclo-rh`

Comment: @Pat Oops, it's my fault, I forgot the command needs to be quoted.

Comment: Your edited command definitely did something. Still no joy. `Installing '/opt/rh/php55/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/geoip.so'` and `extension=geoip.so` exists in /etc/php.d/geoip.ini. Still getting undefined function.

Comment: Ah, I found I had to add `extension=geoip.so` to `/opt/rh/php55/root/etc/php.d/geoip.ini`. I'm still a little confused about what SCL is (and why it's different than previous PHP installations; but that's another topic). Everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: @Pat See for instance [Software Collections Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/2/html/Software_Collections_Guide/index.html).